# QGIS, Euclidean distance analysis

Tags: grass-gis, distance, saga, sextante-qgis-plugin

i wanna generate euclodian distance map for my road data. I 'll use it for multi criteria analysis. I can get it by using Arcgis Euclodian Distance tool but i wanna generate it in QGIS environment. I got Sextante plugin and enabled Grass and Saga tools. But i dont know which tool i must use ??? There is a link about ouput of this anaylsis (below image).

[ESRI The Euclidean distance example](http://ars.els-cdn.com/content/image/1-s2.0-S0098300408001088-gr3.jpg)

Answer (score 4):

Try the Proximity tool.  It does the same thing as Euclidean distance.  It also gives you the option of specifying a distance in terms of number of cells.  I've included some pictures to show you where to find it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I cannot use a polygon layer as input. Any alternative?